# Can a transient field in a class be obtained using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, transient

Can a `transient` field in a class be obtained using reflection? (using `getDeclaredField(..)`)

Comment: Did you find any workaround?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*Yes*, It is a normal field. You can check whether it is transient by:

```
Modifier.isTransient(field.getModifiers());
```

> **transient**: 
>       A keyword in the Java programming language that indicates that a field is not part of the serialized form of an object. When an object is serialized, the values of its transient fields are not included in the serial representation, while the values of its non-transient fields are included.

So no logical reason for it not to be accessible by reflection. It's the value of the field that is ignored (sometimes), not the field itself.

(btw, what hindered you from just trying to call `getDeclaredField("yourTransientField")`?)

Answer (score 3):

`transient` indicates that the field will not be serialized.  The field is still declared by the class, so it is fair game for reflection.

Answer (score 2):

Among all the objects that needs to be serialized there are those one that need not to be serialized. That's why this objects are marked with the keyword transient.

Answer (score 0):

`transient` fields have nothing to do with reflection. The keyword only signals that a field should be skipped during [Java serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization#Java) process. So reflection can access `transient` fields just like any other fields.