# Changing serialization process at run time

Tags: java, serialization

I know about customizing the serialization process by including necessary methods in a class. But is it possible to change the serialization process at run time??
For example, I have defined a field in a class as transient but I want to serialize it at run time. Can this be done and how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can by using [Externalizable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html). See the example here.[enter link description here](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-externalizable-example). You can have to control on what to serialize when and in what form. For e.g. you can [check at runtime if the field is marked transient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256734/can-a-transient-field-in-a-class-be-obtained-using-reflection) and then make a decision.

Comment: I know about this. But this is compile time. My question is about changing it at run time.

Comment: @Newbie cam you explain what you mean by runtime? Let us say if you want to serialize conditionally then you can put that logic in your write/read methods.

Comment: I have mentioned it in the question. For example, I have defined a field in a class as transient but during program execution, i want to serialize it.

Comment: Ok, I know this. It can tell me whether a field is transient, but how to serializable it?? because serialization logic is present in the class.

Comment: @Newbie point is you can't. You need to write your own code for serialization if you want something that is not in spec.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know but I doubt it. Maybe you can do this the other way around by setting the field to null when you dont want it serialized and then dont define it as transient.